# Show that for every odd number n there is a positive integer m such that n=τ(m^2)/τ(m) where τ is the number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I feel that it has to be proved by induction but I am getting confuse with the different variables. I used the formula of τ where it is the product of (a_i +1) where a_i are the exponents of prime factors of m

Comment: I did not find a solution for $n=7$ yet.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Peter The duplicate says, for $n=7$ use $(7, [8, 5, 4])$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I could not figure out what the corresponding $m$ is.